# Perl backticks: flags do not exist

Tags: perl, ls, backticks

When executing the following segment of code,

```
sub list {
    my($self)=@_;
    my $file = $self->{P_Dir}."/".$self->{Name};
    print `ls –l $file`;
}
```

I get this error:

```
ls: cannot access –l: No such file or directory
```

I am not really sure what is causing that, since if I manually type ls -l into the command line, I do not see that error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That `–` that you've thankfully copy & pasted is a Unicode en dash character [(U+2013)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) and not the ASCII hyphen character `-` [(U+002D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm).

Comment: Yes, it seems somewhere copying between Windows and my Linux VM they changed.  I should be more careful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... It works for me though:

```
$ cat test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $file = "rpm.pl";
print `ls -l $file`;

$ perl test.pl 
-rw-r--r-- 1 dheeraj dheeraj 922 2012-10-22 19:56 rpm.pl
```